# Join the values only in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary. I am trying to join the values only. This is the dictionary:

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

My expected output is `123` (it should be 123 without any sorting).

The code I am using:

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
test = ' '.join(d.values())
print test
```

It is showing an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    test = ' '.join(d.values())
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

I am using Python 2.x.

Comment: What error is it showing? Mind that (a) dictionaries are unordered, and (b) in Python-3.x you should write `print(test)`, not `print test`.

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please edit your question to include your error. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Python2 or 3?

Comment: So what is unclear about the error message? `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found`, string joining only works on strings.

Comment: @Arya You cannot `.join()` integers in either Python 2 or 3

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your values are not strings:

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
test = ''.join(str(x) for x in d.values())
```

As [MosesKoledoye pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619572/join-the-values-only-in-a-python-dictionary/44619578#comment76225004_44619578): the order of the keys is not guaranteed, so you might want to do something more elaborate if the order is important. Doing a `str()` on the integer values is vital in any case.

```
''.join(str(d[x]) for x in sorted(d))
```

The above will sort the values based on the sort order of the keys, and sorting by the values themselves is trivial.

Your output doesn't have a space between the digits either, so make sure you join on `''`, not on `' '`.

Comment: You probably want to state it can't always be 123 without any sorting at least in Python 2

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I will thanks.

Comment: @Anthon I was referring to the ones you just removed, just inside of `str.join`. So, `''.join((...))` only needs to be `''.join(...)`.

Comment: @Anthon I was just trying to be polite. It seemed unnecessary to leave that comment there after you made the edit. I would have left it there if I had known how amusing your reaction was going to be.

Answer (score 4):

You need to map over the values with the string function:

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}

test = ' '.join(map(str, d.values()))
```

Note that this solution will not return the values in sorted format i.e the numbers will not be in ascending order. If you want a sorted solution, however:

```
test = ' '.join(map(str, sorted(d.values())))
```

Comment: You probably want to state it can't always be 123 without any sorting at least in Python 2